# ASP.NET Core 8 Web API : publish to IIS fails because file in use (projectname.DLL)

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, publish, .net-8.0

I started facing DLL in use problem when publishing after I upgraded from .NET 6 to .NET 8.

Basically let's start from the beginning, let's say the API is currently idle (not used for some time), I can publish the API no problem, the moment I do first API request, it goes to active (w3wp.exe in task manager is started), right now if I try to publish, it gives me the error.

Now, like I said this become a problem to me once I upgraded to .NET 8.

All of my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API projects have this problem.

All of my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API projects are ok, you can publish as much as you can, of course (the API is unavailable during the publish) but even if the w3wp.exe for that API works, the publish still happens.

I spent a lot of time searching about this problem, anything that I tried (at this point I don't even know what I've tried, its been 3 weeks), it didn't work.

Believe me the last place I want to ask is here but I definitely need help, as of what I'm doing right now, is I'm ending the w3wp.exe process in order to publish, but I need to do it everything I have change which is extra hassle.

Original error message:

> Error
> Web deployment task failed. (The file '(projectname).dll' is in use.  Learn more at:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FILE_IN_USE.
> Learn more at:
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FILE_IN_USE.)    (projectname)       0

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
publishing to remote IIS on windows server

Comment: So you have a local IIS and configured your API for local development - they target the folder on which you are doing a development , right ?  When ever you app pool is running you can publish since your dll's are used by another process ?

Comment: @J.Memisevic no its not local, all are hosted on IIS on a windows server (remotely), sorry for mentioning that

Comment: So you have deployment issues ?

Comment: @J.Memisevic
yeah, the issue is when trying to publish the API and the process is running, it doesn't let me, as described in the question. In production, this is always the case as the API is always in use.

Comment: Your deployment strategy is wrong. When deploying to IIS you should always stop the app pool deploy the website and then start the app pool again. There are a few strategies to keep your site always running but those include more the one instance of your Api and load balancer.

Comment: @J.Memisevic I understand and I've read about more than one instance and load balancer, but since when is this, why with .net 6 is ok ?

Is there any way to stop app pool, publish and start app pool without doing it manually from the IIS from the server, as it will require connection to the remote server every time.

Comment: Not sure how do you do your deployment via pipeline or ?

Comment: @J.Memise
Its very simple project, I do right click publish with target Web Server IIS